# Android NFCDemo: Open URL on browser

Tags: android, nfc

I try to use the android [NFCDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/index.html) on the android emulator because I haven't an android phone.
The demo work well but my question is how to change the MockNdefMessage to open the URL tag on the browser. This an example of NDEFmessage:

```
public static final byte[] SMART_POSTER_URL_NO_TEXT = 
   new byte[] {(byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0xd1,
            (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x01, 
            (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x65, 
            (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0x63,(byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x6d};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to look into the official DevGuide : there is a topic on [NFCBasics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html) and especially how to define [URI in NdefMessage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html#abs-uri).